# Plone make login mandatory on every page but main page

Tags: authentication, permissions, plone

A customer wants to have its Plone site behave like this:

- the main page can be seen by anonymous users
- you have to be registered and authenticated to see any other page
- the site is open for registration, so the forms to authenticate and register should also be made visible by anonymous

How one can approach this?

Is there a way to hook a python script/class/method/function to any request made by the user? Overriding the main_template.pt and adding a TAL call to a method that does these checks would be enough?

The tricky part is that even if the anonymous can only visit the main page, the main page in itself is made up of other content types which should be only viewed by authenticated users (by their restrictions, not because of workflow).

I ruled out, maybe a mistake?, workflow because then everything should be made private but still the global_nav is made out of folders which, if the workflow approach was taken, should be private/non-viewable by anonymous.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you sure that global_nav items are being seen by unauthorized users? If so, there may be some problems in your catalog. AFAIK, that is not Plone's default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- add a state `internally published` to your workflow
- copy permissions configuration from the "public" state into the new state and than remove the "View" permission from the Anonymous User (maintain the 'Access content information', that's the key). Then add all needed transitions.
- put your home page in "public" state
- put everything else in 'internally published' state

This should work because if you link content's information in the homepage, this will work, but if someone try to access a content he will miss the "view" permission and will be redirected to the login.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The global_nav doesn't show the documents with this internally_published state.

Comment: Well actually in my company we have just set-up a similar config for a client,  so, trust me it works :) . Contents in that wf state appear in the global nav and when you click on them you have to login. Most likely you customized your navigation configuration to show only contents in public state. Check it in the control panel. If your configuration is standard then double check your customized workflow and remember to click "Update Security Settings" in your portal_workflow tool.